# Pushing each word to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

If I had a string of text, how would I convert that string into an array of each of the individual words in the string?

Something like:

```
var wordArray = [];
var words = 'never forget to empty your vacuum bags';

for ( //1 ) {
  wordArray.push( //2 );
}
```

1. go through every word in the string named words
2. push that word to the array

This would create the following array:

```
var wordArray = ['never','forget','to','empty','your','vacuum','bags'];
```

Answer (score 36):

Don't iterate, just use `split()` which *returns an array*:

```js
let words = 'never forget to empty your vacuum bags',
  wordArray = words.split(' ');

console.log(wordArray);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/h7CRa/).

And, using `String.prototype.split()` with the regular expression suggested by [@jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169809/pushing-each-word-to-an-array/20169819#comment30068243_20169819) (in comments, below):

```js
let words = 'never forget to empty your vacuum bags',
  wordArray = words.split(/\s+/);

console.log(wordArray);
```

References:

- [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: Might want to handle multiple spaces with `.split(/\s+/)`.

Comment: @Wendy: everything in JavaScript is an Object, including Arrays. If you try running `console.log( wordArray instanceof Array )` that *should* result in `true`, unless that's what you already tried? But since `String.prototype.split()` always returns an Array (so far as I'm aware, from reading the docs a few times), I'm fairly confident it's an Array that's returned.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a possible rephrased version (**non-regex**):

An alternative solution that doesn't involve regular expressions could be considered.

```js
let words = '     practice   makes   perfect  ',
  wordArray = words.split(' ').filter(w => w !== '');

console.log(wordArray);
```

or just use [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
let words = '     practice   makes   perfect  ',
  wordArray = words.match(/\S+/g);

console.log(wordArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to iterate through the array use:

```
let wordArray = [];
let words = 'never forget to empty your vacuum bags';

let wordsSplit = words.split(" ");
for(let i=0;i<wordsSplit.length;i++) {
    wordArray.push(wordsSplit[i])
}
```

But it would make more sense to not iterate and just use:

```
let words = 'never forget to empty your vacuum bags';
let arrOfWords = words.split(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below, it will help.

```js
var wordArray = [];
var words = 'never forget to empty your vacuum bags';
wordArray = words.match(/\b[-?(\w+)?]+\b/gi);
console.log(wordArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested out many methods from StackOverflow and other websites. The method that works for the majority of cases is the following:

```
function stringToArrayOfWords(str) {
    return str.split(' ').filter(w => w !== '')
}
```